# How do I make my website URL turn from https://example.com/file.html to https://example.com/file?

Tags: html, .htaccess, web, url, replit

How do I make my website URL turn from *https://example.com/file.html* to *https://example.com/file*? I am using Repl.it to host my website.

`.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.htm -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.htm [L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.asp -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.asp [L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.aspx -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.aspx [L]
```

Comment: OK, so you tried to implement something. And now you ask something. What is the connection between both? Does your implementation work? yes? No? If not, what _exactly_ does that mean? How did you test? Where is that file you named ".htaccess"? What permissions does it have? Did you enable the consideration of such files?

Answer (score 0):

> I am using Repl.it to host my website.

From the many responses on the `replit.com` forums (such as [1](https://ask.replit.com/t/how-to-enable-htaccess-files/19825), [2](https://ask.replit.com/t/ht-access-php-routers/45560) and [3](https://ask.replit.com/t/how-do-i-protect-a-page-on-my-site-that-i-created-using-replit/33339)), it would seem they do not support `.htaccess` files (or even use Apache for that matter).

Although you can vote on the feature request:

- https://ask.replit.com/t/make-htaccess-file-visible-and-editable-for-the-replit-users/3429